# Laravel order by function for 3-level relation

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

I have this function for ordening a column in a 2-level relation.

```
public function sortByRegionUp(Request $request)
    {
        $hotels = Hotel::with('region')
            ->orderBy(Region::select('name')
            ->whereColumn('id', 'hotels.region_id'), 'asc')
            ->paginate(10);

        return view('hotel.index', compact('hotels'));
    }
```

How do i convert this code for use in a 3-level relation (hasManyTrough)? I want to order  hotels by country->name.

Hotel

- id
- region_id
- name
- ...

Region

- id
- country_id
- name
- ...

Country

- id
- name
- ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function sortByRegionUp(Request $request)
{
    $hotels = Hotel::with('region')
         ->withCount(['region as region_name_for_order_by' => function($query) {
             $query->select('name');
         }])->orderBy('region_name_for_order_by', 'ASC')->paginate(10);

    return view('hotel.index', compact('hotels'));
}
```

Comment: This code has the same effect as my own code. It works well for a 2 level relationship. However, I am looking for the code for a 3 level relationship. I want to sort by country->name, not by region->name.

Answer (score 0):

**Add belongsTo relation in Region Model**

```
public function country(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id');
}

  public function sortByRegionUp(Request $request)
{
    $hotels = Hotel::with('region')
        ->withCount(['region.contry as contry_name_for_order_by' => function($query) {
            $query->select('name');
        }])->orderBy('contry_name_for_order_by', 'ASC')->paginate(10);

    return view('hotel.index', compact('hotels'));
}
```

Comment: This code also doesn't work. It results in error message: Call to undefined method App\Models\Hotel::region.country()